# Rails Mysql2::Error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The password works well, but Rails does not work.

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

```
mysql2 (0.4.3) lib/mysql2/client.rb:87:in `connect'
mysql2 (0.4.3) lib/mysql2/client.rb:87:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `mysql2_connection'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:152:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in `main_loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `rails dbconsole` give you the same error? If so, check your `database.yml` file. There are two possibilities:

- Your username is wrong
- Your password is wrong

Comment: What works? Can you be more specific on what command is giving the error?

Comment: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `rescue in database_configuration': YAML syntax error occurred while parsing /usr/share/nginx/html/blog/myapp/config/database.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 12 column 1 (RuntimeError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:98:in `database_configuration'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/dbconsole.rb:119:in `configurations'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/dbconsole.rb:99:in `config'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/dbconsole.rb:22:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/dbconsole.rb:11:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:86:in `dbconsole'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please edit your question rather than posting more information as an answer.